# Mismatched question index and post

Tags: support, questions, edits

I just [posted a question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078467/excel-what-determines-evaluation-order-in-a-formula).

Then in the index it shows up as modified:

> [image]

but in the question itself it does not:

> [image]

What is the source of the difference?

PS: for a short while, in the index it appeared as having 1 answer (which then reverted to 0). Is it possible that Dylan Meeus answered, and then deleted the answer? Would that be the cause? Should then the legend as modified (or at least the effect from that modification) be reverted as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that Dylan Meeus answered, and then deleted the answer?

That's what happened; he posted an answer and deleted it 19 seconds later. He's still the last person to have done something to the question, even though it was deleting an answer, so he shows up on the index

Comment: This isn't a caching issue. "Last activity" isn't cleared out if the last answer is deleted, so it'll show that basically forever (or until someone else does something to that question).

Comment: @AnnaLear : So the answer is incorrect?

Comment: @sancho.s The answer is correct except for the caching part and even then it's just unrelated, not *wrong*.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah; I guess that makes sense